# Addition as a sequence prediction problem - TensorFlow to PyTorch

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, nlp, lstm

I'm trying to learn seq2seq problems and how to use RNN/LSTM to solve them. I came across this interesting "Learn to Add Numbers with an Encoder-Decoder LSTM Recurrent Neural Network" and started with it. Here's the tutorial I am trying to follow - [Machine Learning Mastery Article](https://machinelearningmastery.com/learn-add-numbers-seq2seq-recurrent-neural-networks/)

So the tutorial makes sense and the TensorFlow code is fairly easy to follow. However, I figured if I want to learn to challenge myself, it would be fun trying to rebuild the entire thing in PyTorch.

Here's my implementation - [Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RLaznuBArz3BRVWUEQweEw-9r99qYXl4?usp=sharing)

But the model just doesn't learn. I've tried to go back, read the documentation of the TensorFlow functions the author is using and tried to find what I need to do in PyTorch to replicate the functionality.

I was wondering if anyone around here might be able to point out what I'm missing, and guide me on it?